# Find the length of the arc of this curve from (-27,9) to (8,4): y^3=x^2

Tags: calculus, arc-length

Find the length of the arc of this curve from (−27, 9) to (8, 4).

$$y^3=x^2$$

I know how to use the simple arc length formula to solve a general equation. What's throwing me off about this problem is the specific points given. Do I just pick either the x or the y values to use in the arc length formula? For example, if I choose to use x values to evaluate:

$$\int_{-27}^8 \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac 49\ x\right)^{-2/3}}\,dx $$

Does this setup look correct? I did it this way and have been getting the wrong answer.

Comment: @EzWin even if I do parameterize it, what would the boundaries be?

Comment: made a mistake. Your idea looks correct.

Comment: @EzWin That's what I thought, but it doesn't give the correct answer. I double checked with a calculator, and I didn't make an arithmetic error.. Maybe there's a trick in there that has to do with symmetry?

Comment: Is it a typo in your question? $l=\int\limits_{-27}^{8}\sqrt{1+(\dot{y})^2} =\int\limits_{-27}^{8}\sqrt{1+(\frac{2}{3} x^{-1/3})^2} $

Comment: @EzWin it's the same as yours, I just simplified it a little by squaring the derivative of the equation already.

Comment: Then its typo, coz it should be $\frac{4}{9}(x)^{-2/3}$. Anyway try to separate at $x=0$ and integrate with different sign.